# Distributed Cache 2013 and Ios

Tags: authentication

Maybe i have a mis understanding of what Distributed Cache does, i took it as having the ability to hold a users session across multiple web applications...so in essence they log in once and then when they travel to another web application in SharePoint...they are not asked to do so again.

If this is the case then i also assumed that in a mobile browser like safari for iPad on ios i would be able to do just that.

However it is not doing that and i'm scratching my head as to what i would need to do to stop it from prompting me for credentials each time i go to a different web application.

Comment: Distributed Cache has nothing to do with user authentication. It is the ability for multiple web front end servers to all maintain a server side cache capability. Previously, individual web servers would hold their own cache, and in a multiple web front end scenario, it is possible that the cache can become out of sync. Distributed Cache is a solution to this.

Comment: That point is understood, the confusion i have is when reading this article... it states... Login tokens are now cached in the new Distributed Cache Service

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219758.aspx

Comment: This actually refers to security tokens which are used to verify that your session for that particular site (which is stored in your browser cookies) is still valid. Unfortunately, when you go to a different web application, it will have a different URL therefore you won't have the cookies that you had in the previous site therefore you're asked for them again. If you don't get this on Windows PCs, this tells me that your environment is using NTLM, if I'm correct?

Comment: We use NTLM and Kerberos in our environment, Kerberos was implamented for the MAC clients we have. Specifically i'm trying to find a solution to the Mobile devices iPads, phones etc...I assumed that leveraging DC in 2013 would take care of that. However it seems that it's on a token basis per web application, so they would still have to get a cookie from each web application they visited. Content, mysite, search etc...

Comment: That's correct.